# How can I transform my time to string and get only the part I need?

Tags: python, datetime, time

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
api_time = datetime.strptime(parsed_json["result"]["parameters"]["time"], "%H:%M:%S")
```

What I'm getting in `api_time` after debugging is `900-01-01 12:30:22`. What I want is `12:30:22` only. I have checked other docs and `.strptime` should have done it but it didn't work.

Comment: api_time = api_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') ##### Use this after you get api_time to proceed further

Comment: api_time = datetime.strptime(
                        parsed_json["result"]["parameters"]["time"], "%H:%M:%S").strftime('%H:%M:%S')

Comment: `api_time` is a [**`datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object (which in the debugger is transformed to a string). You can control the string representation in your program using [**`datetime.strftime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime), e.g. `api_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1: Strip space

One quick solution, if your input doesn't change.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
api_time = datetime.strptime("1900-01-01 12:30:22".split(" ")[1], "%H:%M:%S")
print api_time
>1900-01-01 12:30:22
```

In your case:

```
api_time = datetime.strptime(parsed_json["result"]["parameters"]["time"], "%H:%M:%S")
```

## Method 2: Construct datetime

Or you can just construct your `datetime` object and then access it's `second`, `minute`, `hour` attributes as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
api_time = datetime.strptime("1900-01-01 12:30:22", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "{0}:{1}:{2}".format(api_time.second, api_time.minute, api_time.hour)
>22:30:12
```

Comment: Did you mean api_time.strptime(parsed_json["result"]["parameters"]["time"].split(" ")[1], "%H:%M:%S") if so i have tried to print it and got an error, index out of range.

Comment: when you print `parsed_json["result"]["parameters"]["time"‌​]` what do you get?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert them from datetime to string, then just use string split:

```
a = '1900-01-01 12:30:22'
a.split(' ')[1]

--> 
from datetime import datetime
api_time = datetime(1900, 01, 01, 12, 30, 22).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
api_time.split(' ')[1]
```

Comment: Kindly give a complete answer i can actually follow up on for the 2 issues mentioned, having my output as string, and having only the part i want.

Comment: @Alexis, hi, Alexis, check above -->